# React-webcam enable/disable flash

Tags: reactjs, camera

I'm using react JS  to create a camera application.

I want to be able to save a photo snapshot, change the `facingMode`, to be able to use the font and back camera of the phone. Also, I would like to enable and disable the flash when the `facingMode` is set to the environment.

I used `react-webcam` from npm to start a video stream and create a snapshot.

At this point, I can flip the camera (to use the front and back camera), but can I enable/disable the flash when the back camera is active?

In here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints I found a  constant property called torch that is used for the mobile flash, but I don't know how to dynamically set the vale to true/false

```js
import React from 'react';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const WebcamComponent = () => <Webcam />;

const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [hasEnvCamera, setEvnCamera] = useState(false);

  const [image, setImage] = useState('');

  const [flash, setFlash] = useState(false);

  const capture = React.useCallback(() => {
    const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    setImage(imageSrc);
  }, [webcamRef]);

  const videoConstraints = {
    width: 220,
    height: 200,
    facingMode: 'user',
  };

  const videoFlipConstraints = {
    width: 220,
    height: 200,
    facingMode: { exact: 'environment' },
  };

  const changeCamera = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (hasEnvCamera) {
      console.log(' back camera');
      setEvnCamera(false);
    } else {
      console.log(' front camera');
      setEvnCamera(true);
    }
  };

  const changeFlash = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('change flash');
    if (flash) {
      setFlash(false);
      console.log('flash off');
    } else {
      setFlash(true);
      console.log('flash on');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {hasEnvCamera ? (
        <div>
          <p> camera flip</p>
          <Webcam
            audio={false}
            height={200}
            ref={webcamRef}
            screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
            width={220}
            videoConstraints={videoFlipConstraints}
          />
          <button onClick={changeFlash}>
            {' '}
            {flash ? 'Disable flesh' : 'Enable flash'}{' '}
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>selfie camera</p>
          <Webcam
            audio={false}
            height={200}
            ref={webcamRef}
            screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
            width={220}
            videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
          />
        </div>
      )}

      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          capture();
        }}
      >
        Photo
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const imageSrc = null;
          setImage(imageSrc);
        }}
      >
        Take another photo{' '}
      </button>

      <button onClick={changeCamera}> Change camera </button>
      <img src={image} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default WebcamCapture;
```